# SQLFiddle no output

Tags: sql, schema, sqlfiddle

[image]
When i build the following schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
  CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMER_ID)
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES(1);
```

and run the following query:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUSTOMER;
```

I get no output. Can somebody please explain to me what is wrong?

Comment: Did you build your schema on the left?

Comment: sqlfiddle appears to be dead.  You can build schema but any query appears to time out.  Tried SQL 2014 and MySQL.

Comment: Yes schema is built on the left. Query runs on the right. Output should be on the bottom. I'm supposed to use this site for a school project.

Comment: According to this I should get output where highlighted: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/34124/where-can-i-see-the-result-of-an-sqlfiddle-query

Comment: And no, this code has nothing to do with project, so not marked as homework. I'm just trying to get the tool to actually work before i start =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works just fine. see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abc924/1)
sometimes sql fiddle stops functioning or shows loading error due to server load; perhaps that's why.

Comment: That was basically it. It worked just fine for me during the evening. I finished that project a while ago.

Answer (score 4):

For future readers.

You build the SCHEMA (DDL) in the left pane.

And you do the INSERT and or SELECT (and/or other work) in the ~right pane.

Aka, my "newbie" mistake was putting all my code in the left pane, including any insert/select statements.  D'oh!

Aka, (to the original question), you need to move this statement:

> INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES(1);

to the top of your right pane.

See:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5bc0f/2